# when run docker, error occurred (npm ERR! path /package.json)

Tags: node.js, docker, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, google-container-registry

when docker run (npm ERR! path /package.json)

here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:8

WORKDIR /app
ENV NODE_ENV development

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

app  Dockerfile  env.sh  export-doc.sh  mongo  README.md  redis

/app
images  log  node_modules  package.json  package-lock.json  src  tsconfig.json

when i run the docker...

docker run -p 3000 --name server server:0.1. 
// I want to like 127.0.0.1/3000

error occurred (npm ERR! path /package.json)

how can i modify Dockerfile???

Comment: You're not COPYing your application in.  If you `docker run --rm -it server:0.1 sh` you'll get a shell on the image that just got built, and you should see it's basically empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained here https://nodejs.org/de/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/
try something like this:

```
FROM node:8

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```